# My oracle SQL SELECT query returns on 1 column

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL SELECT query returns with the information being on 1 column and I'm not sure why it does that. When I do SELECT * it appears fine. Any clues?

```
SELECT customer_id, name
FROM customers;
```

[SQL QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHDPV.png)
[TABLE DESC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do02F.png)

Comment: This is some peculiarity having to do with your Oracle SQL client tool, rather than Oracle itself.

Comment: Ok, so my code is fine? Thanks!

Comment: Login to sqlplus and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your Client Tool opens new line for it does not know the length of name column. If you take just first 40 chars from name it should give the expected result.

```
SELECT customer_id, SubStr(name, 1, 20) "NAME"
FROM customers;
```

Comment: SubStr(name, 1, 40) - Sorry***

Answer (score 0):

It is about a "long" `name` column datatype; here's a demo.

```
SQL> desc customers
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMER_ID                               NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> select * from customers;

CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       7369
SMITH

       7499

CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALLEN

       7521
WARD

CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
NAME
<snip>
```

---

What to do?

As you use SQL*Plus, one option is to modify page and line size:

```
SQL> set pagesize 100
SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> select * from customers;

CUSTOMER_ID NAME
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       7369 SMITH
       7499 ALLEN
       7521 WARD
       7566 JONES
       7654 MARTIN
<snip>
```

---

Another option is to format that particular column:

```
SQL> col name format a20
SQL> select * from customers;

CUSTOMER_ID NAME
----------- --------------------
       7369 SMITH
       7499 ALLEN
       7521 WARD
       7566 JONES
       7654 MARTIN
<snip>
```

---

Or, as already suggested, fetch a substring.

Comment: I've given it a try but my results are still coming out with only 1 column. I've adjusted the pagesize and linesize. The odd thing is if I do SELECT * FROM name; that will print the results correct.

Comment: Could you post table description? Are there any settings you've made? Maybe in LOGIN.SQL or GLOGIN.SQL? Also, this *is* SQL*Plus, right?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my original post with the TABLE DESC. Yep, this is SQL*PLUS. Thanks!

Comment: Right; those long VARCHAR2 columns can't fit the screen width and cause *problems*. You said that SELECT * FROM ... looks OK. Could you, please: a) exit SQL*Plus, b) establish connection again, c) run SELECT * FROM ... statement, d) take screenshot which contains all previous steps (only a few lines of output will be just fine, I'm interested in Oracle's respond to steps b) and c)).